# Flutter: Set data to firestore does't write any data and doesn`t throw any erros

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem when I try to write to Firestore in my flutter app with a user signed in with google. When a user press sign in with google button. It signs in with google successfully I can see it in the authentication page in the firebase console. Then I read from firestore if the user has its data in firestore, if the user does not have a document in firestore it returns null and it creates it. It works fine in debug mode but when I turn to release mode it doesn’t work. When I set data to firestore I don’t get any errors thrown so it’s like the set function would successfully wrote in firestore. In release mode, if I register a user with email and password it creates the user profile in firestore without problems. I have two projects one for production and one for development. The development project with de debug app works fine. I’ve cleaned the project, I ran flutter doctor and everything seems to be fine. Also I've checked the firestore rules and they are the same in both projects.

Here is the code that works in debug

```
Future<String> signInWithGoogle() async {
final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
    await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

final auth.AuthCredential credential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
  accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
  idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
);

final auth.UserCredential authResult =
    await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
final auth.User user = authResult.user;

assert(!user.isAnonymous);
assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

final auth.User currentUser = await _auth.currentUser;
assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

var token = await FCMService().getDeviceToken();
DatabaseService databaseService = DatabaseService(uid: currentUser.uid);
var res = await databaseService.getUserData();

if(res == null) {
  print("auth -> getUserDataFromFirestore: El usuario no existe, lo   creamos en firestore con estos datos: "
          "email: ${newUser.email}, nombre: ${newUser
          .nombre}, token: ${newUser.notificationToken}, "
          "telefono: ${newUser
          .telefono}, tipo: ${newUser.tipo}, uid: ${newUser
          .uid}");
  User newUser = User(
      email: currentUser.email,
      nombre: currentUser.displayName,
      notificationToken: token,
      telefono: currentUser.phoneNumber,
      tipo: TIPO_PERSONA_CLIENTE);

  assert(await databaseService.setUserData(newUser) ==
      "Ok");
}

return '${user.uid}';
```

}

```
Future setUserData(User user) async {
return await personasCollection.doc(uid).set({
  'direccion': user.direccion,
  'dob': user.dob,
  'email': user.email,
  'nombre': user.nombre,
  'idEmpresa': user.idEmpresa,
  'identificacion': user.identificacion,
  'notificationToken': user.notificationToken,
  'rolEmpresa': user.rolEmpresa,
  'telefono': user.telefono,
  'tipo': user.tipo,
}).then((val) {
  return 'Ok';
}).catchError((val) {
  return val.toString();
});
```

}

```
Future getUserData() async {
return await personasCollection.doc(uid).get()
.then((value){
  return value.data();
})
.catchError((e){
  throw "$e";
});
```

}

This is the try catch from the UI

```
try {
      var user = await _auth.signInWithGoogle();
      print("sign_in -> usuario se inicio sesión con google, este es su id $user");
     } catch (e) {
         print("sign_in -> $e");
         setState(() {
                          loading = false;
                     });
         showSingleButtonDialog(
               "Error",
               "Algo salió mal, por favor inténtalo de nuevo",
               "OK",
               context);
      }
```

This the debug:

✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk (8.7MB).
I/flutter ( 3955): wrapper -> built
E/FlutterFcmService( 3955): Fatal: failed to find callback
I/flutter ( 3955): wrapper -> built
I/flutter ( 3955): wrapper -> el usuario ha iniciado sesion
I/flutter ( 3955): database -> getUserData: get data del usuario: 6W6yF7OrSsaxDaQgHbBFwzbZjN72
I/flutter ( 3955): auth -> getUserDataFromFirestore: El usuario no existe, lo creamos en firestore con estos datos: email: dropit.informacion@gmail.com, nombre: Dropit Lo llevamos, token: cMteTk7lQsa4lkicSzxobj:APA91bHkjrfj6eJBivqCGqcDkih6FHlhPbwb1C_AKrveqHkeunudF6_QQvyR41XH7-z4lLI7sZSOFFwFOW_0QTWR1-zuSluYMO8ffT-ac8aR-4u_s6miU35XLffXIgzMSo3GAPur44Ge, telefono: null, tipo: 3, uid: 6W6yF7OrSsaxDaQgHbBFwzbZjN72
I/flutter ( 3955): sign_in -> usuario se inicio sesión con google, este es su id 6W6yF7OrSsaxDaQgHbBFwzbZjN72

Comment: I would surround your code in the UI with a try catch and just throw any exceptions caught (Normally if it's a firebase related issue, it's a PlatformException.)  I've had issues with .catchError.   It will not throw any Exceptions on the main thread, which is where you can see them.

Comment: @ScottGodfrey I've sorround it with a try catch and it doesn't catch any errors. I await the signInWithGoogle() method and it prints the firebase authentication data correctly however the firestore document isn't created.

Comment: Can you add the debug console after the signInWithGoogle() method is called?

Comment: if its your first time opening firebase then you need to set your projects db from console first.

Comment: @ScottGodfrey I've added the debug console after the method is called and also the try catch from the UI. The try, catch is working because when I change the SHA certificate it throws an error correctly

Comment: @Henok, it is not the first time I open firebase I've set the firestore db. I've been working like 6 months in this project and when the user sign in with email and password it creates the document in firestore. However when the user is signed in with google it doest create the document and neither throws an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the signInWithGoogle() function, in release mode flutter disable assertions. Instead of assertion use if